# How parse a list of json object from a file in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need to parse a list of Wikipedia articles stored in a huge json document.

The article structure in the json file  is :

```
{"id": "", "revid": "", "url":"", "title": "", "text": "..."}
```

I don't have the name of the object and due this i have some problem to parse it in java.

Some advice?

Comment: Use a JSON library; search for one on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can name class whatever you want. In that class you don't must map every field but you can. The important is to have these same fild names and types as in JSON file

e.g.

```
public class Article {
    private String id;
    private String url;
    private String title;
    private String text;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach for you:

```
package com.json;    

import java.io.IOException;    

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;    


public class JsonToObject {    

    public static void main(String[] args){    

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"id\": \"AF98037\", \"action\": \"UPDATE\", \"activated_at\": \"2020-01-24T03:37:44.951Z\", \"address_contact\": \" \", \"age\": 0}";    

        try {
            ParsedJson gi = mapper.readValue(json, ParsedJson.class);    

            System.out.println(gi.getAction());
            System.out.println(gi.getId());
            System.out.println(gi.getAge());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    

    }

}
```

ParsedJson.class

```
package com.json;    

public class ParsedJson {    

    private String action;
    private String id;
    private String alt;
    private Integer age;
    private String address_contact;
    private String activated_at;    

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }    

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }    

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }    

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }    

    public String getAlt() {
        return alt;
    }    

    public void setAlt(String alt) {
        this.alt = alt;
    }    

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }    

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }    

    public String getAddress_contact() {
        return address_contact;
    }    

    public void setAddress_contact(String address_contact) {
        this.address_contact = address_contact;
    }    

    public String getActivated_at() {
        return activated_at;
    }    

    public void setActivated_at(String activated_at) {
        this.activated_at = activated_at;
    }
}
```